# Normalizing any date string into a given format in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, formatting

I'm working with website content which includes several types of date string (e.g. Atom/RSS feeds). I was wondering if there is a library to normalize these **strings**, or if someone has a gem tucked away for this purpose.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
2014-02-14T12:11:03-05:00
2014-02-14T02:08:00Z
```

becomes:

```
// Only an example format, all that matters is they're the same
YYYY-MM-DD - HH:MM:SS
```

Let me know your suggestions, any formatters will be appreciated :) I googled for a while and couldn't find anything!

Oh, also, even though I tagged this Java (it's what I'm using), feel free to post answers in other languages - I'm sure either I, or someone on the thread, can help convert them.

Comment: You could take a look at [Apache Commons Language](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) which has a [`DateUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html) class which can be handed a list of formats in order to parse a given `Date`

Comment: I up-voted this question because here I am looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such API developed in any language, that takes a date string input of one's interest and identifies and/or returns its date format string.

In my opinion, it should be the content/feed generator that should let the receiver know that, it holds data in a specific `date_field` with *`type="date"`* and *`format="YYYY-MM-DD - HH:MM:SS"`* (as an example). This actually helps the receiver API or renderer (Browser), if required, to convert the same into local/regional format and then apply.

This kind of format directives are seen in XML data for mobile browsers. My observation and practice was on Number formats, Alpha-Numeric combinations. Did not check on dates. And I am not sure if this is still in practice.

```
<input type="text" name="m0" maxlength="22" format="*N" />
```

Let us hope someone implements this for dates as well.

Answer (score 1):

For converting a date string from a format to another format (eg: 2014-02-14T12:11:03-05:00 to 2014-02-14 - 12:11:03):

```
SimpleDateFormat oldFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date d = old.parse("2014-02-14T12:11:03-05:00");
SimpleDateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd - HH:mm:ss");

destFormat.format(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "normalize" you mean convert all the date-time strings to a single consistent, then you definitely should go the way you showed in your first pair of example lines. Those two lines are both using the [ISO 8601](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. While there are other date formats, ISO 8601 is the most sensible and useful.

The "gem" you need is the open-source free-of-cost [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library for Java. Or in Java 8 use the new java.time.* package, inspired by Joda-Time and defined by JSR-310.

Both Joda-Time and java.time use ISO 8601 for their default formats and can parse such strings directly. For other formats, you define formatters for either parsing or for generating strings.

Search StackOverflow for "joda" to find many similar questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Check the javadocs for [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) It describes everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to system accepted timestamp and then into a human readable timestamp. Here's a php example.

```
date("m/d/Y", strtotime($date))
```

Following values for `$date` yield the following normalized values

```
6/1/74     => 06/01/1974
6/1/1974   => 06/01/1974
Jan 1 2013 => 01/01/2013
```